# WAP that takes an integer N from keyboard, computes and display the sum of the numbers from N to (2*N) if N is nonnegative. If N is negative then

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

WAP that reads an integer N from keyboard, computes and display the sum of the numbers from N to (2*N) if N is nonnegative. If N is negative number, then it is the sum of the number from (2*n) to n. The starting and ending points are included in the sum.

Comment: the answer n=int(input("enter an integer: "))
m=0
if (n>-1):
    for i in range (n,2*n+1):
        m+=i
else:
    for i in range (2*n,n+1):
        m+=i
print(m)

Comment: The question is not clear. What's WAP? Does it come from https://www.computertutor.in/resources/type-c-7-write-program-to-compute-and-display-sum-of-integer-from-nto2n/? If so, why asking here and give the answer yourself?

Comment: no it doesnt comes from there but thanks for telling and WAP is write a program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def myfunc(n):
ls=[]

#we are going to append all the number from n to 2n
#and return their sum
#since 2n is also included, therefore end point of loop must be 2n+1

if n<0:
    for i in range(n,2*n-1,-1):
       ls.append(i)
else:
    for i in range (n,2*n+1):
        ls.append(i)
return sum(ls)
```